# Web Scraping with urllib and fixing 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I used this cod to get a web page and it worked well

but now isnt work

I try so many headers but still geting 403 error
this cod work for most sites but i cant get for example

[this page](https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Victorio-Lucchino/No-4-Evasion-Exotica-50418.html)

```
def get_page(addr):
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
    req = urllib.request.Request(addr, headers=headers)
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    return str(html)
```

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you study the meaning of [HTTP status 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) - it usually means you need to authenticate before accessing the URL.

Comment: my cod need something to work for this site i want to get  web page with urllib but i got 403 error in some page (not for Limited access in time for each IP)

Answer (score 0):

Try Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

# initialise browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Victorio-Lucchino/No-4- Evasion-Exotica-50418.html')

# get page html
html = browser.page_source
```

Comment: selenium is very good but i want to know  what is wrong  i use this code for few project  and need to  use  urllib